# How to set monitor on standby after certain period

Tags: screensaver, xset

Machine: **Dell Vostro PC**, System: **Ubuntu 18.04**, Desktop: **Gnome 3.28** running **Wayland**.

Is there a command within Linux so that my monitor goes into standby after a fixed period of idle time?

I know with the GUI I can set the idle time for up to 15 mins through the Settings-->Power selection. But supposing I want to set this period longer, eg 20 mins. I've looked at `xrandr` and `xset` options, but neither seem to give any examples of actually doing this, and I would have expected it to be a common query, but no-one appears to asked it.

Also is there a way of making this setting indefinite rather than just for a session?

Comment: This was answered here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1042641/how-to-set-custom-lock-screen-time-in-ubuntu-18-04

Comment: @ajgringo619. This was more about locking the monitor after a fixed period, not quite what I was asking.

Comment: I was looking at the 3rd answer, part 1.

Comment: @ajgringo619 I'll have a closer look and try the gsettings config. Not sure about this working though. Have you actually tried this method yourself? I thought someone might have an answer with `xset`.

Comment: Testing now - let you know in 30 minutes.

Hmmm...just thought of something. I don't think my test will work in a VM.